# Entities & DTOs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, orm, electron

I'm newbie in JavaScript world, all my enterprise experience is around C# & .NET. I used to apply JavaScript as a secondary language for some web apps. Now I'm trying to improve my knowledge in JavaScript and making simple electron app.

In .NET if there is an interaction with DB through an ORM, usually an app would have DTO and entities separately and map them, the same as I may see is in use for Node.js (based on Internet search). But what about Electron apps? Is it common practice use DTOs and Entities through the mapping, or this way is a bit overwhelming?

Comment: Orm use is a developper choice. You can use any of them if they provide some sort of interface with your language, database and platform. You can roll your own either. You can still have a  look at TypeORM which is Js,Ts oriented

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a connection between DTOs and electron because electron is more like your usual frontend apps. DTOs are for backend to talk with your database.

Here are some DTO libraries I know.

SQL

1. [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/)
2. [Bookshelf](https://bookshelfjs.org/)
3. [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/)

NoSQL

1. [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/)

People use DTOs for the following reasons:

1. Mapping DB ResultSet to Objects
2. Serializing objects to JSON to return to the client.
3. Ease in object properties validation
4. Database Migrations

Items 1 & 2 are the required. Yet it does not apply to node.js.

Here's the following reasons:

1. JavaScript is dynamically typed.
2. Working with native drivers (SQL/NoSQL) already gives you JSON in the server. Thus, no serialization needed to return to the client.

DTOs are great especially if you're new to node.js. Personally, I don't use DTOs in node.js. Main reason is I don't trust the queries generated by DTOs especially for complex ones. I use native drivers and I made tools on top of it. I use json-schema to validate objects and generate typescript type-definitions.

Here are the tools I used instead of DTOs:

1. [AJV](https://ajv.js.org)
2. [Knex](https://knexjs.org)

Here's an example [project](https://github.com/jasper95/api-redis-session) you can look at without using DTOs